# pyspark: train kmeans streaming with data retrieved from kafka

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I want to train a streaming kmeans model with data consumed from a kafka topic.

**My problem is how to present the data for kmeans streamig model**

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])

lines.pprint()
```

This outputs (these are my features separated by '|'):

1.0|2.0|0.0|21.0|2.0

1.0|2.0|0.0|21.0|2.0

Then I want to do this

```
model = StreamingKMeans(k=2, decayFactor=1.0).setRandomCenters(3, 1.0, 0)
model.trainOn(lines)
```

If I combine the two slices of code I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'unicode'> into Vector
```

Comment: Could you share an end to end example plus the versions of all the software modules you are using (Kafka and spark versions)?

Comment: The error logs isn't complete. Can you share the complete version?

Comment: Thanks @MedAli. I just found the solution. I'll post the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue was formatting the stream extracted from kafka. Here is what was worked for a pipe separated data

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})

raw = kvs.flatMap(lambda kafkaS: [kafkaS])
lines = raw.map(lambda xs: xs[1].split("|"))

lines = lines.map(lambda x: DenseVector(x))
```

The second issue was the **dimension of the data**: first parameter of `setRandomCenters` (it should by the same as the number of features)